# How do I adjust the limits of the axes tick marks to be the same as the border in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, margins

I have the following figure and I want it formatted such that the tick marks on each axes are the upper and lower extent of the area bounded by the thick black border.

```
ggplot(WPND, aes(x = Year)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=FOX_LS), colour="black", size=1.2, linetype=1) + 
geom_line(aes(y=FOX_HS), colour="red", size=1.2, linetype=1) +
theme_light() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color= "black", size=11, angle=90, hjust = 
-2, vjust = 0.5)) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 11)) +
ylab(expression("BAI (cm "*{}^2*")")) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 2015, by=5)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60), breaks = seq(0, 60, b=10)) +
theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.5),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'grey', linetype= 'dashed'),
axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"),
axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
axis.text.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")),
axis.text.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")))`
```

figure I've made in ggplot

[image: figure I've made in ggplot]

how I want the tick marks/margins to look (figure made in excel)

[image: how I want the tick marks/margins to look (figure made in excel)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `expand = c(0,0)` argument to the `x` and `y`scales:

```
... +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 2015, by=5), expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60), breaks = seq(0, 60, b=10), expand = c(0,0)) +
...
```

Comment: @CameronM if this solved your problem, please remember to click the green check next to this answer